# How do I make python requirements portable?

Tags: python, deployment

I am not a python pro, but python is really useful, so I'm trying to improve my skills.

I'm working on a project that uses 'requests' and 'grequests'.  Both of these packages have dependencies, which are usually handled by 'pip' or 'easy_install'.  This is fine for a development environment, or for installing to one or two machines, but I need to deploy my project to 200+ machines.  What is the best way to package up my dependencies with my project so that it's portable?

python v2.7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your machine:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

On other machines:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Also, I advise you to look at `virtualenv` tool to work with dependencies in more comfortable way. For more sophisticated solutions (eg, distributed dependencies management), look at `Puppet`. Good presentation from PyCon: [Dependency management with Puppet](http://rcrowley.org/talks/pycon-2011/)

Comment: virtualenv is definitely a good way to go, but I'm not convinced that installing pip on every machine makes sense.  Maybe that's the python way to do things, but to me, it makes more sense to have some sort of build server that pulls down my requirements at build-time, so that I don't have to pull the same dependency 200+ times when I upgrade to the latest version of requests.  Ensuring consistency and auditing seems like it would be difficult.

Comment: @GregB Updated my answer with new requirements :)

Comment: Thanks.  I have a bad habit of shooting for brevity, and then missing key requirements in the process :).  I do use puppet to manage these servers, so this is definitely an option for me.  There's just something about a self-contained package that I find appealing.

Comment: "There's just something about a self-contained package that I find appealing" YES INDEED... bringing python apps to the masses who don't use cli tools. The majority in the world, who just want to download and install, ala app markets ala dropbox!

Answer (score 1):

Use a requirements file for `pip`, or use a deployment tool like [buildout](http://buildout.org/), which supports complex installations and can pin versions for you:

```
[buildout]
versions = myversions
parts =
    mypackage

[myversions]
mypackage = 1.0
requests = ...

[mypackage]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs = mypackage
```